# ASP.Net: Unity Dependency Injection throws exceptions on Controllers

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, owin, unity-game-engine

Essentially what the title says. Here's the full github project:

```
https://github.com/dsidirop/PetTrackerOAuth.git
```

The controller simply never gets instantiated due to an exception internal to the asp.net stack (the full exception is shown at the end):

```
[RoutePrefix("api/account")]
public sealed class AccountController : BaseApiController
{
    private IPetTrackerUnitOfWork _repo;

    public AccountController(IPetTrackerUnitOfWork repo) //this one isn't even getting called
    {
        _repo = repo; // System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof(IPetTrackerUnitOfWork)); //strangely this works just fine
    }
}
```

Unity configuration:

```
  [assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(UnityWebActivator), nameof(UnityWebActivator.Start))]
  [assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethod(typeof(UnityWebActivator), nameof(UnityWebActivator.Shutdown))]

  namespace AngularJSAuthentication.API.Unity
  {
     static public class UnityWebActivator
     {
            static public void Start() => StartWithSpecifiedConnection();
            static public void StartWithSpecifiedConnection(Type typeOfDbContextToUse = null)
            {
                var configuredUnityContainer = ((ConfiguredUnityContainer) ConfiguredUnityContainer.I).Init(typeOfDbContextToUse);

                FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
                FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(configuredUnityContainer));

                 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new global::Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(configuredUnityContainer);
                DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
            }

            static public void Shutdown() => ConfiguredUnityContainer.I.Dispose();
    }

    public class ConfiguredUnityContainer : UnityContainer
    {
        static public IUnityContainer I => _lazyInstance.Value;

        static private readonly Lazy<IUnityContainer> _lazyInstance = new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() => new ConfiguredUnityContainer());

        private ConfiguredUnityContainer()
        {
        }

        public IUnityContainer Init(Type typeOfDbContextToUse = null)
        {
            this.RegisterType(typeof(IPetTrackerDbContext), typeOfDbContextToUse ?? typeof(PetTrackerDbContextProduction), new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            this.RegisterType<IPetTrackerDbContext, PetTrackerDbContextProduction>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            this.RegisterType<IPetTrackerDbContext, PetTrackerDbContextProduction>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            this.RegisterType<IPetTrackerUnitOfWork, PetTrackerUnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            this.RegisterType<IUserStore<IdentityUser>, PetTrackerUserStore>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            this.RegisterType<IRoleStore<IdentityRole, string>, PetTrackerRoleStore>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            this.RegisterType<IPetTrackerRoleManager, PetTrackerRoleManager>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            this.RegisterType<IPetTrackerUserManager, PetTrackerUserManager>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            this.RegisterType<IPetTrackerUserRepository, PetTrackerUserRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            this.RegisterType<IPetTrackerRoleRepository, PetTrackerRoleRepository>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            this.RegisterType(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>), new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            this.RegisterInstance(typeof(HttpConfiguration), GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);

            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Exception Message:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Core.dll

Additional information: Type 'AngularJSAuthentication.API.Controllers.AccountController' does not have a default constructor
```

Exception:

```
System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(System.Type type)    Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController>(System.Type instanceType)    Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Type controllerType, out System.Func<System.Web.Http.Controllers.IHttpController> activator)    Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, System.Type controllerType) Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request)   Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1>(ref System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1 stateMachine)    Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) Unknown
System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)    Unknown
System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)   Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder<System.__Canon>.Start<System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0>(ref System.Web.Http.HttpServer.<SendAsync>d__0 stateMachine)  Unknown
System.Web.Http.dll!System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
System.Net.Http.dll!System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)  Unknown
System.Web.Http.Owin.dll!System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.InvokeCore(Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext context, Microsoft.Owin.IOwinRequest owinRequest, Microsoft.Owin.IOwinResponse owinResponse) Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__0>(ref System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.<InvokeCore>d__0 stateMachine)    Unknown
System.Web.Http.Owin.dll!System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.InvokeCore(Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext context, Microsoft.Owin.IOwinRequest owinRequest, Microsoft.Owin.IOwinResponse owinResponse) Unknown
System.Web.Http.Owin.dll!System.Web.Http.Owin.HttpMessageHandlerAdapter.Invoke(Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext context) Unknown
Microsoft.Owin.dll!Microsoft.Owin.Infrastructure.OwinMiddlewareTransition.Invoke(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> environment)    Unknown
Microsoft.Owin.Cors.dll!Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> environment)   Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0>(ref Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware.<Invoke>d__0 stateMachine)    Unknown
Microsoft.Owin.Cors.dll!Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsMiddleware.Invoke(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> environment)   Unknown
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll!Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.RunApp(System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>, System.Threading.Tasks.Task> entryPoint, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> environment, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult result)    Unknown
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start<Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5>(ref Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.<RunApp>d__5 stateMachine)  Unknown
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll!Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.RunApp(System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object>, System.Threading.Tasks.Task> entryPoint, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, object> environment, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult result)    Unknown
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll!Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.BeginEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e, System.AsyncCallback cb, object extradata)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error)   Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb)  Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpContext context)    Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Unknown
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) Unknown
System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags)   Unknown
[AppDomain Transition]
```

Comment: is that `System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix` right ?

Comment: You have not set the `DependencyResolver` for Web API and that is what the framework cannot initialize the controllers. the one you set was for MVC. `ApiController` uses the DependencyResolver found in the `GlobalConfiguration.HttpConfiguration` or create manually (OWIN).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I had already tried GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new global::Unity.WebApi.UnityDependencyResolver(configuredUnityContainer); but still it throws the very same error. If you can pls download the project and try it out. I'm banging my head against the wall here. Thanks!

Comment: @JoeBlow yes thats System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix

Comment: Hope you have registered the Instance too
`container.RegisterInstance(typeof (HttpConfiguration), GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);`

Comment: @Thennarasan had it commented-out but even after un-commenting it nothing worked. Please be so king to download the project and test it for yourself. In any case thanks for tuning though.

Comment: @xDisruptor: I will add a new comment, since i need to post screenshot to check with you.

Answer (score 1):

Downloaded you project and try to run got the exception as you have posted.

[image]

Currently we are using Unity as IoC Container. IoC container will handle the initialization of controller class. To make IoC container to create the instance of the controller, controller class needs to have a parameterless public constructor - default constructor

we need to add the below,

```
public AccountController() : base() { }
```

[image]

Now when I try to run i am getting below, exception in line 44 - register block

[image]

Is there something I am missing in the configuration? Please check and let me know to further check.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this and sorry for the late response. In your case adding a parameter-less constructor seems to fail to do the trick because you probably don't have a MS-SQL server installed on your machine. You need to install one and configure its name to be SQLSERVER otherwise the ASP.NET infrastructure won't be able to create a DbContext (which causes the errors you have observed). This sort of error is of different nature than the one I'm trying to address here.